# Which elements contain 1 in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of numbers obtained as follows:

```
 sets <- lapply(1:5, function(x) combn(5,x))
```

I want to find the elements in the list `sets` that contain 1 (then 2, 3, 4, and 5). This list contains the combinations of 5 in x, for x=1,2,3,4,5. I want to check which of these combinations contain 1.

For instance, for the list `sets`, the first one contains it, but second to fifth don't, sixth to ninth do, and etcetera. So I would like to get a vector indicating this: `TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...`

Comment: I'm note sure what you're searching for. All elements in `sets` contain 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. There are also 5 lists in `sets`, so what do you mean with "second to fifth don't, sixth to ninth do, and etcetera"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea via base R can be,

```
unlist(lapply(sets, function(i) colSums(i == 1) > 0))
```

which gives

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[22] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: But the list `sets` only contain 31 elements, which are to be checked to contain 1.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it

Comment: Updated, have a look - I will add explanation as soon as possible (can't right now)